# how to enumerate $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the argument below in this book I don't know why did the book need to subtract k - 1. In particular, given (m,n) we have it lies in the diagonal k = m + n - 1 and it is the mth point of that "diagonal".

[image: ][1]]

[image: k - 1 why do we need that?]

Comment: Where do they subtract $k-1$?

Comment: In the second image @Arthur

Comment: I still don't see it. What are they subtracting $k-1$ from? In which sentence?

Comment: In sentence 5, but yeah we are counting until d - 1 diagonal not d diagonals. That is why we subtract d -1 not d.

Comment: Do you mean when they say "by first counting the points in the first $k-1$ diagonals"? And do you really mean to ask something along the lines of "why are they subtracting $1$ from $k$ in $k-1$, rather than just using $k$?"

Comment: Yes, I stated that above. Though, maybe not very precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point $ (m,n) $ lies in the diagonal $ m+n-1$.

for example, the point $ (1,1)$ lies in the $ 1+1-1=1 ^{\text{st}} $ diagonal.

The point $ (2,3) $ is in the $ 4^{\text{th}} $ diagonal.

If the point $ (m,n) $ lies in the diagonal $ d $, its rank will be the number of points in the former diagonals $1,2,...,d-1$ plus $ m $, or
$$h(m,n)=1+2+...+(d-1) +m=$$
$$\frac{(d-1)(d-1+1)}{2}+m$$
Now, replace $ d $ by $ m+n-1$.